# How do I use the :not() selector for many values in js

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-selectors

I am coding on js and I was trying to get all the checkboxes that have the class 'some-class', the name 'someName[]' and NOT the ones with value of 'typeOf : category'. Something like this:

```
<input class="some-class" type="checkbox" value="{"typeOf": "category", "ids":["12345678"]}" name="someName[]">
```

I was trying something like this:

```
 checkboxes: $('.some-class[name="someName"]:not([value="typeOf : category"])'),
```

This didn't work. I guess you guys can help me. Thank you all :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Using a filter() function might give you more flexibility than creating an ugly selector

```js
$('.some-class[name="someName[]"]').filter(function(){
   return !this.value.startsWith('{"typeOf": "category"') 
}).prop('checked', true)
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
Shouldn't match: <input class="some-class" type="checkbox" value='{"typeOf": "category", "ids":["12345678"]}' name="someName[]">

Should match: <input class="some-class" type="checkbox" value='foo' name="someName[]">
```

Answer (score 1):

Use `value*=` to match a substring of `value`.

And since the string you're trying to match contains quotes, you need to put those in the selector. The whitespace also has to match the value exactly.

```
$('.some-class[name="someName"]:not([value*=\'"typeOf": "category"\'])')
```